# Mathematical Expression for multiplication and addition of binary arrays

Tags: notation, binary-operations

Assuming I have two binar arrays with 3 bits. Array `A = 1,1,0` and Array `B = 0,1,1`. 
Now I want to perform bit-wise AND operation (or you can say multiplying) between A and B and then add the bits of the resultant array. For the above example the result will be: `(1*0) + (1*1) + (0*1) = 1`.

How can mathematical express this which will look good enough to put in a research paper?

Answer (score 2):

You cab define the bits of $A$ as $a_i$ then write $\sum_ia_ib_i$

Comment: @ Ross Millikan yes, by adding "the sum and the product being taken with their usual meaning in boolean algebra".